# How to convert multiple files to mp3 in Thunar custom actions?

Tags: mp3, thunar, convert, thunar-custom-actions

I have added a simple command `avconv -i %f %f.mp3` to [Thunar's custom actions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ThunarCustomActions) to convert a selected media file to mp3 (in the same folder and with the same name).

[image]

What would be the command that can be added in the same way that would allow selecting multiple files or an entire folder to convert them to mp3 (with the source's folder and name)?

I expect them to be converted **one by one** (**not** in parallel, that is, **not** all at the same time) - but I was wandering if that could be done with one context menu command after selecting multiple files.

---

It looks like **avconv does not support multiple files per input** (see comment under [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/249561/47206)), **I am not asking necessarily for a command that includes `avconv`, but for any other solution**.

Comment: I don't know the answer but are you sure you want to do something like that? CPU usage will be very high during the conversion.

Comment: @vasa1: thanks for noticing that the formula "instead of one by one" is misleading: i want them converted one by one, but after selecting them all and running one command from context menu. i'll edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a little, on how Thunar handles multiple files. Basically, you can use `parallel` ([website](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)) to handle a lot of files.

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
```

So I would start with the following:

```
parallel avconv -i '{}' '{}.mp3' ::: %F
```

By default, it only does one job at a time. If you want to use multiple CPU cores in parallel, try `parallel -j 4 ...` for 4 jobs in parallel. Also check out `man parallel`.

---

In order to run it in Thunar's custom actions, this should be embedded like so:

`xfce4-terminal -e "parallel avconv -i '{}' '{}.mp3' ::: %F"`

---

To convert to [other audio formats supported by `avconv`](https://askubuntu.com/a/286657/47206), just replace `mp3` with that - but: take into consideration other issues like:

- **`flv` and `mp4` files contain `aac` audio** and converting that to other audio formats may entail unwanted results - more [here](https://superuser.com/q/593869/162573). If the `aac` file has about 95 kbps bitrate converting directly to `mp3` would work, because the default bitrate for the `mp3` would be 192kbps, which is a good option (according to [here](https://superuser.com/a/593907/162573)). If the `aac` file has a different bitrate, the `mp3` should be modified accordingly.
- `aac` is a lossy format, and converting it to other formats should be considered in the context of the larger issue that **converting between lossy formats is not recommendable**. Even more, **converting from a lossy format to a lossles one is pointless**.
- **a better option than converting `aac` to `mp3`** would be to just extract the `aac` audio into a `m4a` container, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/294426/47206).

Answer (score 1):

This will not stand as accepted answer.

Initially I was not thinking about a GUI. But, this is a way of doing it too. It will not convert directly, but will add selected files to Soundconverter list. (The main advantage is that supplementary settings are at hand.)

The command to be added to custom actions is

`/usr/bin/soundconverter %F`

Appearance conditions: video and audio.

Comment: This has the nice side effect, that you can see the progress.

Comment: @queueoverflow yes, if soundconverter would always work, which it does not